# Using ColdFusion session variables in PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion website that is currently running well with login/register modules. I want to use my ColdFusion session in PHP. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Not automatically.  They're two separate servers.  The best you could do would be to create a coldfusion page that would export its session variables into a form, and then automatically submit that form into a php page... and vice-versa to take it back to coldfusion ... but that would create a horrible level of overhead.  Why are you wanting to add php pages to a coldfusion website?

Comment: @WolfmanJoe Actually this is a big existing website but client don want to make it more in coldfusion.

Comment: I would recommend telling the client that if they suddenly don't like Coldfusion, and want to add php pages to a coldfusion website, that they need to price out redoing the entire website in PHP first.  Otherwise, the overhead is going to be extremely high, and create a LOT of risk factors.

Comment: Same domain/site using two languages?  You can probably use cookies but you'll need to write cf code to set the cookies before php can use them. Sounds like you're headed into a real bad situation be sure to keep the suicide hotline number handy

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, no it's not really possible. CF and PHP cannot share in memory sessions variables. However, there are other alternatives such as using cookies.

I used that approach once because a client wanted to share sessions with PHP Forum software. I simply grabbed it using cookies, by finding what cookies were being set ie `<cfdump var="#cookies#">`. Then converted those cookies into sessions variables. (If you need it the other way around, try doing it in reverse.)

Another possibility is sending data securely by using encrypted URL variables. But we need to know more about your goal. Can you explain exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Another Note: I had to do this because a client wanted to share sessions with PHP Forum software. I simply grabbed it using cookies by finding what cookies were being used <cfdump var="#cookies#"> and then I converted those cookies into sessions. If you need it the other way around try doing it in reverse.

Comment: Who voted him down, he has 1 rep which means he can't leave a comment, cut him some slack.  @CoryFail don't get discouraged, StackOverflow isn't like a normal forum, answers are intended to be "answers" and not questions.  You don't have enough rep to comment yet so it's understandable.  Whoever voted you down forgot that little detail.

Comment: I'm not discouraged. I'm trying to get 15 rep so I can comment. It's a bit difficult to really do if keep getting voted down.

Comment: Actually [commenting requires 50+](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) .. unfortunately. Not sure why this was downvoted. It was not just a comment/request for clarification. The response a) gave "an answer" to the question and b) suggested two possible alternatives. Upvoting to offset the -1.

Comment: upvoted to help with the rep, and it isn't an terrible suggestion. :)

Comment: upvote as this is indeed a suitable answer (better with Leigh's edits).