# Passing Session Data Between ColdFusion and PHP

Tags: php, session, coldfusion

I have been working on a client project to pass session data from a ColdFusion login page to PHP.

Does anyone know how to pass session variables from ColdFusion to PHP?

Comment: Did you try to search? See: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?175644-Pass-a-CF-session-variable-to-a-PHP-page

Comment: Store your session variables in a database.

Comment: we used folllowing way to rectify the issue.after user loggedin successfully in coldfusion we redirect user to php page then we set php session and again we redirect user to coldfusion page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your database.

1. Generate session variables in ColdFusion.
2. Store the variables in your database.
3. Initialize the PHP session.
4. Query the database and populate the PHP session variables.

Comment: Actually the US Navy has proven Cold Fusion back in 2008/2009

Comment: Lesson learned - don't name products after nuclear reactions to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I would to convert the session data into something PHP can understand.  So, I would probably convert it to JSON and then store it in a database.  Once you have crated the base PHP session query the db and process the JSON data into your PHP session.

You will only be able to do this with data that can be serialized such as strings, arrays, and structures. You could however create your own serializer for data not natively handled. If your ColdFusion session contains objects or binary data you won't be able to transfer those over.

Comment: I would not describe arrays or structures as simple values.

Comment: @Dan, I think in the **context** of what can and can't be serialized into JSON, arrays and structures could be called "simple". In contrast, objects (like instantiated CFCs and Java objects) and binary data are too "complex" to serialize into JSON.

Comment: In the context of CFML, `isSimpleValue( AnArray )` is false. The correct term/distinction is _serializable_ and non-serializable. And it only applies to CF's built-in implementation of JSON serialization - there is nothing stopping a developer from writing their own custom serialization of their objects (along with suitable deserialization on the PHP side); it's just not built-in functionality.

Comment: My use of the term "simple values" was inaccurate. I have edited my response to reflect that. What i was trying to convey is that it will only work with session data that is serializable.  Yes Peter, you could roll your own serializer to handle things that ColdFusion cant handle natively.

Answer (score 1):

CF and PHP cannot share in memory sessions variables. However, there are other alternatives such as using cookies.

I used that approach once because a client wanted to share sessions with PHP Forum software. I simply grabbed it using cookies, by finding what cookies were being set ie `<cfdump var="#cookies#">`. Then converted those cookies into sessions variables. (If you need it the other way around, try doing it in reverse.)

Another possibility is sending data securely by using encrypted URL variables.

You can also refer to this question:

[Using ColdFusion session variables in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543084/using-coldfusion-session-variables-in-php/16550187#16550187)

Comment: I would not use cookies for this.  First, you then expose your server side session data to the client.  Also, what if the cookies are not passed or they are blocked?  You don't want to rely on a client for something that can be handled on the server.

Comment: Which is why I also suggested the time sensitive encrypted URL token. This will allow you to pass the variable securely without the need of a database. Depending on the amount of data the needs to be passed a secure token may be the way to go.